# What do I do when I get a "sync session failed to start" message when syncing iPhone to itunes?

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization

The context is that I'm restoring my wife's new replacement iPhone from a backup. It already did the first sync, where it gets all the settings and whatnot, but not the apps.  Tried the second sync, where it normally transfers the apps, but I'm getting the error message.

Comment: Is the iPhone registered with her iTunes/Apple account?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On your iPhone, force close all the Apps in the multitask window. Depending on your version of iOS, you do the following:

On iOS 7 and before:

- From the Home screen, click the Home button twice.
- Tap and hold on the app.
- When it starts to jiggle, tap the X to close it.
- Repeat until all the apps have been closed.

On iOS 8:

- From the Home screen, click the Home button twice.
- Swipe the application preview window upwards to close the app. (you can close multiple apps at once)
- Repeat until all the apps have been closed.

Now do a Soft reset of your iPhone:
Hold both Home and Sleep button for around 10secs until you see the Apple logo then release. After it returns to Home screen, connect to sync and see if this resolves the issue.

*Source: https://discussions.apple.com/message/18381241#18381241*

Comment: Also, you may need to close iTunes before reconnecting the phone.

Comment: Did all the steps, still no luck on my iPhone 5S, running iOS 9.3.2

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac with macOS Big Sur 10.6 and my iPhone 12 with iOS 14.8, I needed to [restart my iPhone](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201559) to resolve this. (Force-closing all running phone apps didn't work.)

Answer (score -2):

just update your itunes on pc with apple software update

Comment: Hi Ashraf, and welcome to Ask Different! On this site, we are looking for answers that completely answer the question, with detail and sources. Please update your answer to explain why it is correct and offer more steps to help the asker. Thanks, and happy answering!